# Does anyone know of other publications by Hertha von Dechend, co-author of "Hamlet's Mill"?

Tags: source-request

"Hamlet's Mill" emphasized the Precession and resettings for new World Ages.  Where can similar views be found?

Comment: Are you looking for *any* publication by Hertha von Dechend, or just those concerning the specific approach to archaeoastronomy presented in "Hamlet's Mill"? Are you also interested in publications from other authors supporting similar views?

Comment: Both.  I've written about these things but I am new to StackExchange and don't know whether I am allowed to "advertise" by providing references.

Comment: If those references may help clarify your question, they are welcome.

Comment: Relevant publications include: J. Saul, The Tale Told in All Lands (2013); Wm. Sullivan, The Secret of the Incas (1996); Harald Reiche's contribution to Astronomy of the Ancients (1979); and J. Saul, What the Stork Brought: African click-speakers and the spread of humanity's oldest beliefs (2019).

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking for citations.  Hamlet's Mill is referenced to varying degrees in:  When They Severed Earth from Sky by Elizabeth Wayland Barber and Paul T Barber, Wisdom of the Myth Tellers by Sean Kane, Book of the Sun by Marcell Jankovics, The Seven Story Tower:  A Mythic Journey Through Space and Time by Curtiss Hoffman, The Transformation of the Hummingbird:  Cultural Roots of a Zinacantecan Mythical Poem By Eva Hunt, The End of Time: The Maya Mystery of 2012 by Anthony Aveni, Signs in the Sky:  The Astrological and Archaeological Evidence for the Birth of a New Age by Adrian Geoffrey Gilbert, Myth:  A New Symposium (which cites Cosmology, History, and Theology edited by Yourgrau and Breck, as if that book refers to Hamlet's Mill, but I skimmed it and didn't see any references), The Myth of Replacement:  Stars, Gods, and Order in the Universe, The Saturn Myth by David N Talbott, The Power of the Bull  by Michael Rice, The Invisible Landscape:  Mind, Hallucinogens, and the I Ching by Terrence and Dennis McKenna, Maya Cosmogenesis 2012:  The True Meaning of the Maya Calendar End-Date by John Major Jenkins, Imaginary Landscape:  Making Worlds of Myth and Science by William Irwin Thompson, etc.  This list includes books by both academics and popular works, and a few of them are critical of the arguments in Hamlet's Mill.  There could be misspellings in the titles and names.  I might have once found a book with Plato in its title (?), but then I lost track of it and forgot the title.  There was a very extensive website on these topics by Australian Gary David Thompson that listed many works that refer to Hamlet's Mill and had detailed biographical information about the authors, though I think it was completely against the book's arguments, but its web hosting service shut down around August or September 2023.  Maybe it can be found archived or will by reposted at some point.  I might have copies of some pages and there is the Internet Wayback Machine.  I didn't know about J Saul and Harald Reiche.  There might be additional references listed under axial precession, astrological age, Mithraism, etc on Wikipedia.  I think Worthen and/or Rice note arguments about Mithraism and precession.

Addition - Actually, Gary David Thompson's website was preserved on web.archive.org/  Skimming, Thompson mentions these authors as referring to Hamlet's Mill or making similar or related arguments and some are cited in Hamlet's Mill:  Jerome Y Lettvin, Deborah Porter (reviewed by William Nienhauser, Junior and Kazuo Matsumura), John Lear, Bendt Alster, Norman Newton, Kenneth Brecher and Michael Feirtag, David White, Jane Sellers (Juan Villar? or is he a reference on Sellers?), Linda Schele, Leonora Leet, Jean Richer, Bjorn Jonsson, (probably critical reviews of William Sullivan's book by Gerardo Aldana, Arij Ouweneel, and Susan Niles), N. J. Girardot?, Nedim Vlora and Giuseppe Tucci in 1997, Florence and Kenneth Wood, B. G. Sidharth, Hennie Kruger (review by H.A.J. Kruger ?), Richard Thompson, the Barber and Barber book I mentioned is reviewed at skepticalhumanities.com/category/critical-thinking/ , Roy Taylor 2005, David Kelley and Eugene Milone 2005, Roopa Naragan, Keith M. Hunter and online?, Brian Pellar, David Mathisen, Emmeline Plunket 1908, Rose Hammond (review by Francisco Vaz de Silva), David Pankenier (review by Daniel Patrick Morgan), Gísli Sigurðsson in a 2014 book edited by Timothy Tangherlini, Christopher Johnsen, Martin Sweatman and Alistair Coombs, Alessandro De Lorenzis, Andrew Collins, Klaus Albrecht 2017 in a book edited by Wolfschmidt, Cundrun, Zelia Nuttall, Marion Popenoe Hatch, Gordon Brotherton (has an essay in Myth:  A New Symposium), Clemency Coggins, Giulio Magli, John Major note [www.aeonjournal.com/articles/samson/samson.html](http://www.aeonjournal.com/articles/samson/samson.html) , Wolfram Eberhard and Rolf Mueller, Edward Schafer, George Cox, Max Müller, John Fiske?, Ernst Siecke, Viktor Rydberg, Abraham Victor Rydberg?, Charles François Dupuis, Noël-Antoine Pluche (1739), Macrobius, Comte de Volney, Anton Krichenbauer, Friedrich Leberecht Wilhelm Schwartz, Eduard Stucken, Georg Hüsing, Hugo Winckler, Alfred Jeremias, Gerald Massey, Albert Churchward, John O'Neill, James Hewitt, George St. Clair, the famous Joseph Campbell made a similar argument, Albert McIlhenny?, Leo Frobenius, Johannes Hertel?, William Robertson Smith?, Aldabert Kuhn?, Carolina Lopez-Ruiz? (reviews by Anthony Mangieri and Johannes Haubold), Harald Haarman and Joan Marler, Mary LeCron Foster, Lionel Sims?, Jacques Cauvin, Alice Kehoe, Mario Codebò, Günter Martiny, Brian Hayden, Carl Jung, René Adolphe Schwaller de Lubicz, John Didier (review by Michael Saso), Godfrey Higgins, Jean Sylvain Bailly, Phil Norfleet,  Abraham Aronow, William Stahlman, Harald Reiche, Roberto Bottini, William Joseph Bisson, John Lear, Vito Francesco Polcaro, Amanda Laoupi [www.drgeorgepc.com/DisasterArchSocCultLaoupi.html](http://www.drgeorgepc.com/DisasterArchSocCultLaoupi.html) , E. J. Michael Witzel, Alan Bond and Mark Hempsell?, Leroy Ellenberger, John Major Jenkins note edj.net/mc2012/mill1.htm , Walter Saltzer, Yas Maeyama, Rubellite Johnson, John Mahelona, Sally Weber, Elizabeth Cavicchi, Gerald Gresseth,  Bartel van der Waerden, Abraham Seidenberg, Euan MacKie (critique by Clive Ruggles and Gordon Barclay), Albert Kainzinger, Jerold Matthews, Hilda Davidson, Amanda Barusch, Bradley Schaefer, Hugh Kolb?, Mott T. Greene, Audley-Miller, Lucy and Dignas, Beate, Ernest McClain, Marius Schneider, Michael O’Kelley,   Matt Kane, Constantin Volney, Sabine Baring-Gould, Jarita Holbrook, Alexander Marshack, Thomas McEvilley, David Pingree, Stansbury Hagar, Fritz Röck, David Ulansey on Mithraism, François Henri Stanislas Delaunaye, Robert Taylor, Bál Tilak, James Hewitt, Stansbury Hagar, Franz Schröder, Tara Mata/Laurie Pratt, Eduard Seler, Karl Nowotny, Thomas Barthel, Ferdinand Anders, Witold Balcer, Michael Kamienski, William Stirling etc.

Catastrophe by David Key might be of interest, but its argument about a worldwide collapse isn't related to precession.

Probably mostly hostile reviews of Hamlet's Mill:  Philip Morrison, Cecilia Payne-Gaposchkin, Edmund Leach (de Santillana replied in the New York Review of Books in 1970; I think there is a link on the relevant Wikipedia page), David Leeming, Rebecca Bradley, Harald Reiche, Philip Morrison, Carroll Quigley, Arthur Meadows, Heino Eelsalu, Bernard de Voto, Michael Feirtag, Jaan Purvel,Lynn White Junior, Geoffrey Kirk, Hilda Davidson, Albert Friedman, Guy Davenport, J.-P. Roux, Frederic Amory, etc.

Graduate research into the authors - Marco Sensi and Eleonora Loiodice in Italy  Obituaries by Nathan Sivin, Uta Lindgren, and Richard Flavin.  More mentions, by Steven Wolfe, Luisa Passerini, Otto Neugebauer, David Lindberg, Charles Olson, Cid Corman, Jason Colavito, and Myrto Petsota.  Elizabeth Eisenstein 1980 refers to de Santillana's review of a book by Yates on Giordano Bruno.  Also, apparently the various editions of Hamlet's Mill have slight differences that might be of interest.

Discussions on the History of Astronomy Interest Group listserve Hastro-L:
Information here:  astro.uni-bonn.de/~pbrosche/hist_astr/ha-hastro-l.html ?

This information comes from members.westnet.com.au/gary-david-thompson/page9e.html , but the provider closed down recently.  An email was mentioned.  Gary David Thompson, not an academic in a related field, basically condemns Hamlet's Mill, but he researched its arguments and origins very deeply.  He missed some of the works that cite it, though.

Another addition:  There is an article by von Dechend in Festschrift: W Hartner, but I don't know the content.

Answer (score 0):

at the Frobenius Institute in Frankfurt am Main there you
will have access the Nachlass Server:
https://www.frobenius-institut.de/sammlungen/nachlaesse
there you will find further material by Hertha von Dechend.
With the best wishes
Axel Klaudius